# Spring-Boot: Default controller avoids loading static resources

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

In Spring-Boot, besides normal controllers, I want a Controller, that catches all unknown requests. (also known as "fallback controller" or "default controller")

This is working for me:

```
@Controller
public class Default {
   @RequestMapping()
   public @ResponseBody def() {
      return "default";
   }
}
```

But if I call static resources, they resolve as well to this default-controller.

```
curl localhost:8080/sdkjfh -> "default" --- fine!
curl localhost:8080/test -> "test" --- fine - output of "test" controller!
curl localhost:8080/img/me.jpg -> "default" --- NOT fine! I want an image here!
```

How can I tell spring-boot, to serve static content AND having a default-controller?

Comment: Why do you want that? You yust plan to do a 404 page or something else? (Because there are better things for 404 pages.)

Comment: No, I have to call a legacy app in case of all pages, that my app will not handle. So it is not a normal 404 display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the "catch-all" handler-method and handle **404** errors explicitly.

You need to customize the container-behavior and register a view that will be resolved on a `404 NOT FOUND` (see [Spring Boot - Error Handling](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.9.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-error-handling)):

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer containerCustomizer(){
    return new ErrorPagesCustomizer();
}

private static class ErrorPagesCustomizer implements EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer {
    @Override
    public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
        container.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "/404"));
    }
}
```

Map the `/404` in your controller. Notice that the "catch-all" handler-method has been removed:

```
@Controller
public class DefaultController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }

    @ResponseStatus(value= HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    @RequestMapping(value = "/404", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String handleNotFound() {
        return "default";
    }
}
```

Comment: That's working very well. Thank you! And almost perfect. I just can't get the logged-in user in the "handleNotFound()" method. I'm using Spring-Security. So adding the "Prinicipal" as method parameter or  "Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();" is not working. Any idea? Anyways: Thank you!!

Comment: Although being a new question - the default `Security filter chain dispatcher types` need to be adapted to `security.filter-dispatcher-types=ASYNC, FORWARD, INCLUDE, REQUEST, ERROR` (see `application.properties`/`application.yml` - http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties)